# Making changes to a file and saving it into another file (python)

Tags: python, io

I want to import a .txt file with the following data:

```
no
a
no
a
b
c
no
```

change it to a list (*or some other data type*):

```
mylist = ["no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no"]
```

and save it into a new .txt file

What I came up with so far:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as my_file, open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in my_file:
        words = line.split()

        for n, i in enumerate(words):
            if i != "no":
                words[n] = "yes"
                i == words[n]

                outfile.write(i + "\n")
```

As a result, I want a file with the following data:

```
no
yes
no
yes
yes
yes
no
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*my_file.txt*

```
no
a
no
a
b
c
no
```

*code*

```
with open('my_file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    text = f.read()

with open('outfile.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join([i if i == 'no' else 'yes' for i in text.split('\n')]))
```

*outfile.txt*

```
no
yes
no
yes
yes
yes
no
```

Sometimes its just easier to do things in individual steps.

Comment: @dgr379 i change `if i != 'no'` to  `if i == 'no'` to match your expected output. It is a conditional statement inside the list comprehension